# How do I find IIDs for Office outgoing COM interfaces in C++ without MFC or ATL?

Tags: c++, com, ms-office

I am writing an application that needs to handle events fired by Office - things like 'before print' or 'new file'.

From various articles and examples I understand I should use the `IConnectionPoint` interfaces.
I got the `ConnectionPointContainer` for Word.Application using QueryInterface.
Now I want to run `FindConnectionPoint`, but I have to give it the IID of the interface I am looking for, and I don't know where to find that! 
I thought of running `EnumConnectionPoints`, but that will give me all the connection points and I don't know how to identify which are the ones I need.

How do I know the IID?

Answer (score 0):

There're two possible scenarios:

- you find a description for that event interface somewhere (for example, a .h file describing the interface)
- you get a type library - either in a separate .tlb file or embedded as a resource into the COM server .dll file and use OleView to read it or `#import` directive in Visual C++ to import it and get it converted into a C++ interface definition with named constants for IIDs.

You might also use `IConnectionPointContainer::EnumConnectionPoints()`, then `IConnectionPoint::GetConnectionInterface()`, but just getting the IID is of no value if you don't know the interface definition in the first place, to one of the above will still be needed.

Comment: Your reply together with the one from Hans were very helpful.  Nevertheless I'm still stuck :-(.  I opened MSWORD.OLB in the OLE viewer, and did indeed find the interfaces I need.  The problem is that when I use these in FindConnectionPointer I get a CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION error.  The progID I used to find the ConnectionPointContainer was Word.Application .

Comment: BTW, I also tried to import MSWORD.OLB, but I got compilation errors on msword.tlh. I couldn't find anything else relevant to word that I could import.

Comment: @rimono: You shouldn't use ProgIDs for that, use interface IDs - there should be an interface named something like "WordWhateverCoolThingsEvents" - apply `__uuidof` to it and this will get you the IID.

Comment: I admit I am confused by the different IDs. The argument I gave FindConnectionPoint seems to be correct - it is the IID I found in MSWORD.OLB, after running on it IIDFromString.  I see in the debugger that it is indeed called IID_IApplicationEvents2, which is what I intended. Maybe the problem is in the ConnectionPointContainer from which I call FindConenctionPointer. I first ran CLSIDFromProgID on 'Word.Application'. I then ran CoCreateInstance on this CLSID with IID_IUnknown, and with the result called QueryInterface for IID_IConnectionPointContainter. Does this make sense?

Comment: @rimono: Looks reasonable so far. Yes, you create a component instance and query it for `IConnectionPointContainter`.

Comment: @rimono: Have you looked at this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309294 ?

Comment: I got it to work! I used the IID of a slightly different interface and now it works.  I hope this interface gives me the events I need! Thanks for your help!